# Problems with my text background border (css)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a background border around some text.  For some reason the border around the text cuts at the top.  It still wraps around the text, but the top is cut off.

Here is my css code for the text background:

```
.blue_bg{
background-color: blue;
padding: 5px;
border:1px solid;
border-radius:30px;
max-width:100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

extra:

Here is the css that changes the text and when I take this code out the text changes, but the text border works as intended. 
Here is the code:

```
.market-product-overlay  {
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 700;

color:white;

position: absolute;
left: 0%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -20px;
text-align: center;  
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 100;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: scale(0);
-moz-transform: scale(0);
-o-transform: scale(0);
transform: scale(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please post a *complete* code example. A single CSS rule isn't going to do the trick.

Comment: Something above Your text field cut top border... Like j08691 wrote, post complete code example... btw. `overflow: hidden;` ? why?

Comment: I have added extra code that may help.  I added overflow:hidden because I read something that said it would help, but didnt do anything.  I took it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  overflow:hidden in the market-product-overlay was the problem! took that out